# word_count(s) > Homework for counting letters in a text

Tags: ruby

My homework is to count the letters in a string regardless of the upper or lower case ... so far I have this which I still don't make it work, ideas?

```
def self.word_count_from_file(filename)
    s = File.open(filename) { |file| file.read }
    word_count(s)
end

def self.words_from_string(s)
    s.downcase.scan(/[\w']+/)
end

def self.count_frequency(character)
    counts = Hash.new(0)
    for chatacter in characters
        counts[character] += 1
    end
    # counts.to_a.sort {|a,b| b[1] <=> a[1]}
    # sort by decreasing count, then lexicographically
    counts.to_a.sort do |a,b|
        [b[1],a[0]] <=> [a[1],b[0]]
    end
end
```

Comment: See the `chatacter` in the for loop, it should be `character ` as in `counts[character] += 1`.

Comment: you have typos here (`chatacter`), call a method that doesn't exist (`word_count`), and have some sorting logic that I'm not sure why you need from the question prompt ("count the letters in a string"). Maybe we should back up a bit - can you post the actual original question prompt, and show the error you're getting?

Comment: this is what I am getting  
>>>>   undefined local variable or method `apple' for main:Object
(repl):1:in `<main>' <<<<   
I would rather say "count the characters in a word" but those were the words from the teacher

Comment: `apple` appears nowhere in your code, so that error cannot possibly be caused by the code you posted.

Comment: That is what happens when I run it trying with the word apple ...

Comment: Anyway, better you edit your question to stay on topic: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you need to count words and not characters, I guess you expect to call the class as:

```
WordCount.word_count_from_string('Words from this string of words')
```

or

```
WordCount.word_count_from_file('filename.txt')
```

Then you need two class methods calling other methods in order to get the result. So, this is one option to make it work:

```
class WordCount
    def self.word_count_from_file(filename)
        s =  File.open(filename) { |file| file.read }
        count_frequency(s)
    end

    def self.word_count_from_string(s)
        count_frequency(s)
    end

    def self.words_array(s)
        s.downcase.scan(/[\w']+/)
    end

    def self.count_frequency(s)
        counts = Hash.new(0)
        for character in words_array(s) # <-- there were a typo
            counts[character] += 1
        end
        counts.to_a.sort do |a,b|
            [b[1],a[0]] <=> [a[1],b[0]]
        end
    end
end

WordCount.word_count_from_string('Words from this string of words')
#=> [["words", 2], ["from", 1], ["of", 1], ["string", 1], ["this", 1]]
WordCount.word_count_from_file('word-count.txt')
#=> [["words", 2], ["this", 1], ["in", 1], ["of", 1], ["string", 1], ["a", 1], ["from", 1], ["file", 1]]
```

Note that both `word_count_from_file` and `word_count_from_string` call `count_frequency` which calls `words_array` in order to get and return the result.

---

To be more Ruby-ish (`each`) and less Pythonic (`for`), this is an alternative version using also instance variable (`@s`) in order to avoid passing parameters (`count_frequency` instead of `count_frequency(s)`, etc.).

```
class WordCount
    def self.word_count_from_file(filename)
        @s = File.open(filename) { |file| file.read }
        count_frequency
    end

    def self.word_count_from_string(str)
        @s = str
        count_frequency
    end

    def self.count_frequency
        words_array.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |word, cnt| cnt[word] += 1 }.sort_by(&:last).reverse
    end

    def self.words_array
        @s.downcase.scan(/[\w']+/)
    end
end
```

Call as before.